# Const in C function declaration and implementation

Tags: c, function, compilation, constants, function-prototypes

I have a function declared in `code.h` and implemented in `code.c`.
it goes like:

```
void someFunc(const char*);
```

and

```
#include "code.h"
void someFunc(const char* str){ printf("%s\n", str); }
```

Now I found out I can remove the `const` in any *one* of the files (leaving it there in the other) and it compiles & runs with no errors.
I wonder what's the meaning of this?
Is one of the files the only one that matters?

It might sound like just an unimportant niche behaviour, but this fact means that a missed `const` can go unnoticed.

Comment: Did `code.c` remember to `#include "code.h"`?

Comment: yes it does, I'll add it here so there's no mistake

Comment: At least with GCC (on Ideone.com) I get errors for this, perhaps you should specify what compiler you're using?

Comment: Rename `code.c` to `code.cpp` and you will find the difference with and without `const`.

Comment: Which compiler and target?
My gess is that could be architecture dependent, PCs and ARMs for example use Von Neumann, where RAM and ROM code goes in the same adressing space, so your value could be const or non-const that it will be acessed in same way (just differing in the possibility to be edited), but PICs uses Harvard architecture (where the address and accessing is different for ROM or RAM) so in these devices you NEED to know what you are trying to read so you can go fetch in the right bus

Comment: I use GCC on Ubuntu 16.04 x64. I didn't configure a target so I guess it's the default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens if declaration and definition of a function don't agree on whether an argument is `const` or not?

You should get a compilation *error*.

> What to do?

*Update* your compiler.

---

With gcc 4.2.1, I am receiving an error, if I remove `const` from either the header or the source file:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c code.c
code.c:3:6: error: conflicting types for 'someFunc'
void someFunc(const char* str){ printf("%s\n", str); }
     ^
./code.h:1:6: note: previous declaration is here
void someFunc(char*);
     ^
1 error generated.
```

With gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10), I am getting the same behavior.

Same behavior with gcc's 7.1.0 version, online in [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/):[image]

My guess is that the behavior your are experiencing is architecture/compiler's version dependent.

Comment: I updated my compiler and now it works (gives me error). It showed no warnings as well before that

Comment: Good job @OdedSayar! =)

Answer (score 0):

In C, a diagnostic is required if function declaration and function definition are both visible to the compiler, and don't match.

If your compiler is actually a C++ compiler, the declaration and definition need not match - since they will be considered overloads.   However, if both overloads are not defined, there will be linker errors  (compilation units call the overload they see a declaration for, and linking fails since that function is not defined).

Other compilation units which have visibility of the declaration from the header but not of the definition will compile if arguments being passed are correct, and fail otherwise.   In both C and C++.

If your code consistently builds and runs, then your compiler is not behaving in a standard way (e.g. compilation options that make it not comply in this regard).    Or there is some problem with the build process (such as an object not being rebuilt if a header or source file it depends on changes - which means the executable corresponds to an older version of your source).